# Officially sanctioned way to play back audio from resource under Qt5.x

Tags: audio, qt5, embedded-resource, playback

I want to play .wav files from Qt5 in a supported way. It is important that the sounds are stored inside the binary as resources.

After some research I have found some alternatives:

QSound - simple playback of audio. Does not support many formats, and does not support playing from resources.

QAudioOutput - stream raw audio directly ot audio output. Leaves the task of managing formats to you. With many audio files, keeping them in raw format becomes a hassle. Also one misses opportunities to compress the audio with for example mp3. Also there are issues related to reliability of playback as one has to also manage/optimize buffers and other low level primitives to get smooth playback.

QMediaPlayer - relies on native backend to play back all supported formats on different platforms. Does not support playing back from resources. Some have advocated solutions where one would store resources to temporary file before using this. I find such hackery repulsive at best.

Phonon - Not officially supported anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered after a lot of trial and error that the QMediaPlayer object has a second parameter to the setMedia() method that accepts a stream object. By using this I have successfully played back my audio directly from resources.

We bypass the limitation of QMediaPlayer where it is unable to pass resource urls to native backends by opening the resource urls manually and streaming the data to QMediaPlayer.

Time for some code:

```
void MyClass::play(QString name, qreal vol){
    const QString fn(":/audio/"+name+".wav");
    if(0==file){
        file=new QFile();
    }
    if(0!=file){
        if(file->fileName()!=fn){
            file->close();
            file->setFileName(fn);
            if(file->exists()){
                file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
            }
            else{
                qDebug()<<"MyClass::play ERROR: audio file not found: "<<fn;
            }
        }
        else{
            file->seek(0);
        }
        if(file->isOpen()){
            if(0==player){
                player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
            }
            if(0!=player){
                QMediaContent mc;
                player->setMedia(mc,file);
                player->play();
            }
            else{
                qDebug()<<"MyClass::play ERROR: could not create player for "<<name;
            }
        }
        else{
            qDebug()<<"MyClass::play ERROR: audio file not open for "<<name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`QSound::play( ":/someoptionalfolder/myfile.wav" )` works just fine for .wav files stored in resources.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The original answer doesn't even compile and leaks like a sieve so I wanted to add this answer, which is documented and works just fine with .wav files stored as resources.  For brevity: what more do you want to know?